# how to include "MSVC Runtime.exe" in my MSI installer proj, and have it be run if it's not installed?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, runtime, action

i want to have the "vcredist_x86.exe" included in my installer package.

requirements:
1) built in to the msi file, not a separate package, not a separate install
2) runs automatically as part of single installer
3) only runs if not already installed
4) does not leave extra copy of itself on users hard drive
5) succeeds to build installer file from command line scripts
6) installer must succeed when run

what i tried:
1) project->properties->config props->build->Prerequisites, then check "Create setup program to install prereq components", then check "Visual C++ Runtime Libraries"

**problems**:  violates all requirements except 6, which is moot.

2) in installer pro, show "File System", then add "vcredist_x86.exe" to the user's desktop or application folder, then under "Custom Actions", under "Install", right click->Add Custom Action, then pick "vcredist_x86.exe" from the install location.  then select it, then in "Properties" under "Arguments", change "/Install" to "/Install /qb!" (this should cause the install to be "Unattended install with no cancel button"

**problems**: violates requirements 3, 4 and 6.  As to 6: when running the installer, it fails with the message "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."  That would be me, and i do not know what to do.

Comment: ignore requirement 5, that part is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was to use IExpress and have the thing it executes be a shell script (.bat file).

in the .bat file, have it create the "vcredist_x86" folder and move the "vcredist_x86.exe" into it, then just run setup.exe

this meets all my original requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some prerequisite rules and best practices:

- they use separate packages
- installed only when required
- handled by an EXE bootstrapper
- most of them cannot run as part of the main MSI installation process

Most of these break your requirements. Another approach is using the Visual Studio merge modules from "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x727h8b.aspx

Visual Studio setup projects cannot install merge modules conditionally, so they will always be installed. Other setup authoring tools allow you to condition merge modules based on their associated feature:

- create a search which determines if the merge module is installed or not
- condition the merge module feature with that search result

A third option would be to include just your application dependencies:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317(VS.90).aspx

In this case only your application will have access to the runtime. This approach supports conditional install:

- create a search which determines if the runtime is installed
- use that search to condition each dependency file

Comment: i'm sorry if i've come across as if i know what i'm talking about.  I don't completely understand this process at all.  If we could simply solve issue #6 from my second try, i'd be happy.  i think i'm just passing the wrong command line arguments.  i'm willing to let go of issues 3 and 4.  I have no idea how to "create a search which determines if the module is installed", i thought there'd just be an installer option i could select which does this, as what i'm asking seems fairly common.

Comment: Your second approach is not supported. A simple solution is to use a prerequisite. Most installers use them, so you could give up your requirements for simplicity. If you want to use a conditional merge module or file, you need to learn how installers work and how to configure a setup project. Try reading the articles I mentioned. If it's still too complicated, you can always try a commercial setup authoring tool. They are easier to use, but you have to purchase a license.

Comment: Okay, well, i'm willing to give up requirements 3 and 4.  5 is moot, that was my fault and it's fixed.   the reason i want it *included* in the MSI file is that people tend to just run them directly from "inside" the zip file, and if you have "files" in the zip file instead, it tends to break.  You say "for simplicity", perhaps you mean for me the developer.  Actually what i'm going for is simplicity for the n00b user.  they just want to run one installer and have it, well, install everything.  even asking a new user to run a separate installer from a readme file is asking too much.

Comment: does/can a "prerequisite" get automatically run from the installer?  the whole point is to make it "one click" to install.  is there any way to get what i'm asking for using the visual studio MSI creation tool or python MSI creator?

Comment: Yes, I meant simplicity for you. Making a complex installer simple for the end user usually requires a commercial setup authoring tool. It needs more power than Visual Studio can offer. Prerequisites in VS are handled by the EXE bootstrapper automatically. It downloads and launches them. The downside is that you have two files (EXE and MSI). But there are tools which can pack them into a SFX archive.

Comment: well wait, that sounds good but i want to make sure i understand.  you say "Prerequisites in VS are handled by the EXE bootstrapper automatically. It downloads and launches them."  Are you saying that, if i include this as a prereq, then when the n00b user simply runs my .msi installer (even from inside the zip file), that it will automatically download and run the "vcredist_x86.exe"?  cuz that's exactly what i want.

Comment: Yes, the bootstrapper downloads and launches the prerequisites you add to your project.

Comment: okay, well, this is great, i think.  here's my final question:  when i build the installer now (With the prereq), i see that it creates a "setup.exe" file, and next to it a folder "vcredist_x86", with the "vcredist_x86.exe" inside it.  are these files then copied INTO the .msi file that gets created?  Because, what I do is just zip the .msi file, all by itself with nothing else, and I send that zip file to users.  Will this work or will it break because it expects that the "setup.exe" and the folder will be included?

Comment: You need all these files: the EXE, the prerequisite installer, MSI etc. All of them must be distributed to your users. An user can then launch the installation through the main setup EXE. If you want to pack them all into a single setup file, you can try using IExpress: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346760.aspx

Comment: I definitely want only one EXE, and this IExpress thing would totally have worked except for one thing: it can't create folders in the temp directory.  My setup is this:  
  
    folder/
        MyInstaller.msi
    Setup.exe
    vcredist_x86/
        vcredist_x86.exe
  
and therein lies the problem.  when these files are extracted via the IExpress installer, the hierarchy is flattened and the Setup.exe file can not find the vcredist_x86.exe file.  
  
1) is there a way to have the IExpress extractor create a folder?  
2) is there a way to tell MSDev to NOT create a folder?

Comment: Was hoping @Cosmin would know where i could go from here?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can configure how IExpress extracts the files. If you still can't get it to work, you can try using a commercial tool, for example Advanced Installer (it can import your VS setup project). Even Microsoft deprecated Visual Studio setup projects and started recommending commercial alternatives.